# How to configure the APIM's virtual network such that it uses a VM as backend and forwards all HTTP requests to this VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to configure APIM to forward all HTTP requests to a VM on port 3000, where an Express JS App is running.

I am following this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2#enable-vnet-connectivity-using-the-azure-portal-stv2-compute-platform

I face an issue:

I have two subnets:

1. `default`: this is a subnet where the VM is running;
2. `subnet-apim`: this is a subnet created just for the APIM; It is now empty;

APIM's network is now "None". I am trying to configure the APIM's virtual network to "external", with the subnet `default`. I thought that if I can do this, then in the APIM when I create a blank API, I can just add the VM's private ip address as "Web Service Url", e.g. http://10.0.0.4:3000.

However, this keeps failing - In the APIM portal,
I have selected the virtual network and the subnet `default`.
I have clicked the "Apply" button.
I have clicked the "Save" button and waited for the APIM finish updating.
However, the APIM's network section still shows "None".
The change never took place.

After some search I realized that I cannot configure to the `default` subnet because `default` has no delegation;

But when configuring delegation for this `default` subnet, it fails because:

```
Failed to save subnet 'default'. Error: 'Delegations of subnet dev-vnet/default cannot be changed from [] to [Microsoft.ApiManagement/service] because it is being used by the resource /subscriptions/cb9f3d5f-937b-4ba3-93b6-123qwe123qwe/resourceGroups/default/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/earth-john-dev78_z1/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1.'
```

Basically the `default` subnet is not empty because there is a VM running in it. Therefore it cannot be delegated to the APIM service.

Now I am facing a dilemma:

I can configure the APIM's virtual network to "External" with the subnet `subnet-apim`, but it is a different subnet from the VM's subnet. SO I cannot forward requests using the VM's private ip address.

I should configure the APIM's virtual network to "External" with the subnet `default` in order to forward requests to VM's `http://10.0.0.4:3000`, but it is not possible.

So how am I supposed to configure the APIM such that it uses a VM as backend and forwards all HTTP requests to this VM on port 3000?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out I made a fundamental false assumption here that VMs in different subnets cannot communicate with each other using the private IP address.

This is not true.

Azure VMs within the same VNet can communicate with each other using their private IP addresses, even if they are in different subnets. Subnets are primarily used for managing network security boundaries (via NSGs) and traffic routing, rather than controlling connectivity between resources.